# Ordering two matrices after a third matrix (using %in%)

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have three factors/matrices (NFA,RX and LDC). First, I want to order every row in NFA ascending and RX should be ordered in the same way as NFA. This works. But then I want to seperate the factor NFA into two groups (G1 and G2). Both groups should be new ordered (seperately) after the scheme of the third factor LDC. My Code gives me a wrong sorting, but I do not know why.

## Data

`NFA<-matrix(c(4,9,5,3,1,7,  12,51,15,6,9,3,  9,5,1,11,3,8,  5,9,7,18,21,17),4,6,byrow=TRUE)
RX<-matrix(c(1,3,7,1,5,4,   6,12,3,8,3,5,   4,4,5,34,8,2,  5,7,11,5,13,17),4,6,byrow=TRUE)
LDC<-matrix(c(7,1,5,9,4,3,  12,51,6,3,9,15,  8,3,11,1,5,9,  9,5,7,18,17,21),4,6,byrow=TRUE)
columns <- ncol(NFA)`

## First Sorting:

`C<-t(apply(NFA, 1, order))
NFA.neu <- matrix(NFA[cbind(c(row(NFA)), c(C))], ,columns)
RX.neu <- matrix( RX[cbind(c(row(NFA)), c(C))], ,columns)`

## Ordering every group after the scheme of LDC

`G1 <- 1:(columns/2); G2 <- (1+columns/2):columns`
`for (i in 1:nrow(LDC)) {`
  `nfa <- NFA.neu[i,]; ldc <- LDC[i,]`
  `o1 <- order(ldc[nfa %in% ldc[G1]])`
  `o2 <- order(ldc[nfa %in% ldc[G2]]) + columns/2`
  `o<-c(o1, o2)`
 
  `NFA.neu[i,]<- NFA.neu[i, o]`
  `RX.neu[i,]<-  RX.neu[i, o]`
`}`
The problem is that within group1 and group2 I have the wrong order.

The right solution should look like this:

`Solution<-matrix(c(1,4,3,7,5,9,  6,3,9,12,51,15,  3,1,5,8,11,9,  9,5,7,18,17,21),4,6,byrow=T)`

Maybe someone has a hint for me? I do not know where my mistake is.

Thank you in advance,

Jordan

Comment: I do not completely understand your problem and your solution dataframe but you get a similar C matrix using ordering per group with an approach like this: `apply(LDC, 1, function(x,y) order(y,x), c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3)))`. You add (`rbind`) a grouping row and sort by this and the target row.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. My main problem is the ordering in o1 and o2 in my code. Here I want to order every row of the matrix "NFA.neu" after the sequence in LDC. But my sorting is not in the sequence of LDC and I do not know why.

Comment: OK, but are you sure that your provided `Solution` Matrix is correct?

Comment: Oh no, I had a mistake in my solution matrix. Sorry for that. I am confused. The correct solution should be `Solution<-matrix(c(1,4,3,7,5,9,  6,3,9,12,51,15,  3,1,5,8,11,9,  9,5,7,18,17,21),4,6,byrow=T)`. Now, the code gives the right numbers in both groups, but the sorting within the group is wrong.

Comment: your first row of NEU after sort is 1,3,4,5,7,9. would you like to demonstrate how you sort this based on first row of LDC 7,1,5,9,4,3? I dont see how you can arrive at 1,4,3,7,5,9.

Answer (score 0):

the first line in NFA.neu is in ascending order:
matrix(c(1,3,4,5,7,9),1,1).
Then I want to make two groups:
G1: 1,3,4;
 
G2: 5,7,9

Now, I have the matrix LDC: 7,**1**,5,9,**4**,**3** (it contains the same values as NFA.neu).
In LDC the 1 comes before 4 and then 3. So my new order should be in G1: 1,4,3.

For Group 2: In LDC comes the 7 before 5 and then 9. My new order for Group 2 should be 7,5,9.
If you combine G1 and G2, then you get: 1,4,3, 7,5,9
The same method I need for line 2-4.

I hope that it is a little bit more clear and thanks for your efforts and help,
Jordan

Comment: The `G1` and `G2` vectors in this post are different than the group vectors in your first post. Please use the edit button and revise your first post. And please be more precise and omit unnecessary things.